# FullCalendar update event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have FullCalendar connected with database and working very well. I've added feature 'seen' to events currently there are 4 states -> Seen, Unseen, Approved and Denied. 
So I managed to solve problem with seen and unseen, and also my approve and deny buttons work as well except I cant update events after I do update in my database.

I have defined callback for eventRender which will render events depending on seen field.
Here is code which will be executed when I click on Approve button:

```
$( "#approve_event" ).click(function() {
    $.get('_pm_calendar.php', {
            'control':'updateSeen',
            'id':$('#event_id').val(),
            'status':3
        }, function(data) {
            if( data == "1") {
                var evt = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', $('#event_id').val());
                evt.seen = 3;
                calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', evt);
                calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

But I still need to refresh page to see changes. If data is equal to 1 that means the query was successful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to show changes, so execute query, I changed events status in database, now i need to show that change back to user - update & rerender event in fullCalendar.